# Error reporting in Visual Studio for MSBuild running xUnit.net

Tags: msbuild, xunit.net

I am about to set up MSBuild to run xUnit.net as described [here](http://xunit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=HowToUseMSBuild&referringTitle=Home).

This is working. But when xUnit reports an error, the actual error and the line/file in which the error occurs are seperated into two different error messages in the Visual Studio "Error List"-window.

The file, line and column show the values of my project file instead of the source file of my unit test. Double clicking on the error to get to the failed test is not working.

Is this a known problem? I couldn't find any information on this. A solution for my problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, I've found that all of the unit test options seem to do this. I don't get it.

If you use the Exec MSBuild task, it works better. Not perfect, but better.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a [minor fork](https://hg01.codeplex.com/forks/moswald/fixesformsbuildtask) to the xUnit project that does what you want. Use the `xunit` MSBuild task.

Comment: This was before xUnit switched to git, and my fork was destroyed. I *believe* xUnit 2 will fix this issue.